# Session handling in MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, session, mean-stack

Mean is new to me. Also full stack development is new to me.  So i dont have any idea to figure out how to handle sessions in web app.  Which aspects should handle on server side and client side. In detail please.
Will appreciate any help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution will to implement Jwt on express side.

- Authentication request is sent from front-end to the server.
- Express side returns back a JWT token after authentication to the front-end.
- Save the jwt token on front-end in local/session storage.
- Send JWT token from the front-end with the requests that require authentication.